# How to disable `New Account Setup` wizard in Mozilla Thunderbird

Tags: macos, thunderbird

I have installed Mozilla Thunderbird 2.0.0.23 (20090812) on Mac OS X 10.5.8.

I do not use it for reading mail, I just use it to open a mail here and there if I am interested how it will be displayed in it.

Every time is start Thunderbird I get `New Account Setup` wizard. I do not want to create an account. Is there a way to disable the wizard?

I have searched the web and this site, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know of any way to disable the new account wizard but you could add an account with fake information and then set it to not automatically check the mail for that account.  Thunderbird should stop bugging you about adding a new account and it shouldn't cause any problems (unless you click 'get mail' for that account).

Comment: Good idea. I just added empty `News & Blogs` and it stopped bugging me. Thanks! :)

Comment: This worked for me too on TB 60.3.3 on Windows 8.1 (which, almost 10 years after the question was asked, still has the same behaviour of showing the wizard every time when you have never created an account). In addition, after deleting the empty account, the wizard still doesn't show up. Possibly the key is in the fact that "Local Folders" are created once you create any account, and they remain after deleting the last account.

Answer (score 12):

My use case - use Thunderbird to view `.eml` files.

What worked for me.

- Open an email with Thunderbird.
- Cancel the setup wizard.
- From the opened email view, go to `Edit` -> `Account Settings`.
- Go to `Account Actions` -> `Add Feed Account`.
- Click on `Next`, then click on `Finish`.

Done. You won't be asked to create an account again.

Comment: Exactly my use case as well :D thanks for a nice solution

Comment: Sad, that there isn't a "Cancel Wizard and Don't Ever Remind Me Again" option, but this is second best.

Answer (score 6):

Set Thunderbird to "offline mode", then go through the wizard.  It won't attempt the tests and you can select "advanced" and it should drop you back to the accounts configuration page and continue setting up there.

Comment: **Very good!** Putting Thunderbird to offline mode is the key. This seems to be the only way to get out of the black wizard cave without hitting invalid and uncorrectable domain names. Even an unknown domain in online mode and the following half-manual quick config doesn't help as much. It's really a shame why Thunderbird won't even let you configure everything you need. Because it's wrong and it's standing me in the way to do it right. I was simply unable to tell it the correct host names...

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to disable the [Autoconfiguration Wizard](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Thunderbird:Autoconfiguration) for when I setup a new email account, because it always got in the way and even tried to find a "valid" configuration when setting up tunneled (`localhost:1993`) mail server endpoints. I tried to disable it altogether by setting the following options in the [Config Editor](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/config-editor):

```
mailnews.auto_config_url = http//localhost:666
mailnews.auto_config.fetchFromISP.enabled = false
mailnews.auto_config.fetchFromISP.sendEmailAddress = false
mailnews.auto_config.guess.enabled = false
```

Now, when setting up a new email account, the *Autoconfiguration Wizard* is still printing `Looking up configuration: Mozilla ISP Database` after the first step, but one is now able to click on `Manual Config` and fill out all fields manually. Make sure no "Auto" or "Autodetect" fields remain, as we *don't* want autodetection:

[image: Mail Account Setup Window]

Finally, click on `Advanced config` instead of "`Done`" and the well-known "Account Settings" window should come up with the account now already in place.